# What is the Biblical basis against being able to predict the date of the end of the world?

Tags: biblical-basis, eschatology

Recently, there have been a few people (e.g. Harold Camping) who have predicted the end of the world.  Historically, the Jehovah's Witnesses (Watchtower Bible & Tract Society) have also predicted the end of the world several times.

What is the Biblical basis for the claim that no one can predict the date that the world will end?

Comment: I'm pretty sure end-of-the-world predictions are not just a "recent" thing, nor is it just a "few". Indeed, the sheer volume of doomsday prediction literature probably outweighs the original common biblical sources many many times over.

Comment: There were, apparrently, as many predictions of the end of the world at the end of the first millenium as there were at the second.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Jesus taught that we might be able to read the signs that it was near, but that no one would be able to know what day the end would come:

> "From the fig tree learn its lesson: as soon as its branch becomes tender and puts forth its leaves, you know that summer is near. So also, when you see these things taking place, you know that he is near, at the very gates. Truly I tell you, this generation will not pass away until all these things have taken place. Heaven and earth will pass away, but my words will not pass away. **But about that day or hour no one knows, neither the angels in heaven, nor the Son, but only the Father.** Beware, keep alert; for you do not know when the time will come. It is like a man going on a journey, when he leaves home and puts his slaves in charge, each with his work, and commands the doorkeeper to be on the watch. Therefore, keep awake—for you do not know when the master of the house will come, in the evening, or at midnight, or at cockcrow, or at dawn, or else he may find you asleep when he comes suddenly. And what I say to you I say to all: Keep awake." —[Mark 13:28-37](http://www.biblestudytools.com/nrs/mark/passage.aspx?q=mark+13:28-37)

Answer (score 4):

**What is the Biblical basis against being able to predict the date of the end of the world?**

Here are a couple of more verses.

> Acts 1:6-7  When they therefore were come together, they asked of him,
>   saying, Lord, wilt thou at this time restore again the kingdom to
>   Israel?   And he said unto them, It is not for you to know the times
>   or the seasons, which the Father hath put in his own power.
>
> 1 Thessalonians 5:2-3  For yourselves know perfectly that the day of
>   the Lord so cometh as a thief in the night.   For when they shall say,
>   Peace and safety; then sudden destruction cometh upon them, as travail
>   upon a woman with child; and they shall not escape.