# Will World end on Oct 7,2015?

Tags: judgment

Is this believe of Christians because I have listened this from Christians?

If this Biblical prediction proves wrong then will Bible be called a false book?

Comment: Your previous question almost exactly the same as this one was closed because it didn't meet the site guidelines (it may be reopened because it's now been edited to attempt to bring it in line). Please learn [how we are different to other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites?s=1|1.9041) and [Types of questions that are within community guidelines](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3409/types-of-questions-that-are-within-community-guidelines?s=2|0.4193) to avoid further wasted effort.

Comment: Which previous Question? it is my first Question in this plateform

Comment: this one: [What reason did a group of Christians have that the world would end on Oct 7, 2015?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/42966)

Comment: Answer: No, it didn't.

Answer (score 3):

No, if that prediction proves wrong the Bible will not be called a false book because it doesn't make that prediction. On the contrary it clearly states in plain language in several places that we are not and  will not be in a position to know a date for the end of the world ahead of time.

On the other hand whatever people are running around making this prediction *will* be considered false prophets by most of Christianity. Almost all major branches or Christianity hold to (at least on paper) the Biblical teaching that people who make false predictions prove themselves to be false prophets.